# Original name O"Brien getting in file is "O/"Brein" in hive. How to fix

Tags: hive

I have data in my hive table with the name O"Brien, But when I am fetching it through hive query and putting it into a file I am getting like "O/"Brien". How to fix it in hive.

I am getting like in the file: ABC,"O\"BRIEN",ABC,ABC,date
Original data in the hive table is : ABC,O"BRIEN,ABC,ABC,date

Comment: Putting it in what file, of what type? Anyway, who spells the name `O'Brien` like `O"Brien`, i.e. with a double quote instead of an apostrophe? And are you really telling us that Hive is also changing `Brien` to `Brein`?

Comment: What happens when you put the data using hive tools?  Does it also get it wrong?  If not, then it's probably not hive where the problem is.  Can you post some code that shows the problem?

Comment: This is hive query which I am using in scala code.

Comment: Putting it into simple file. Comma separated file. I do have data with double quote